asp-route-memberId being generated as query parameter instead of route parameter
In ASP.NET Core 5, when I used asp-route-..., I could get the URL like this: /Member/Update/2.
But now it is generated like this: /Member/Update?memberId=2
I don't understand what changed in .NET 8.0 that makes me include it in my [HttpGet] as [HttpGet("Update/{memberId}")]. I am feeling like something is missing.
Do I remember it wrong, or did they change it in newer versions? Is there any other way to change this behaviour?
My routing:
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

My Index view:
<td class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <a asp-action="Info" asp-route-memberId="@item.Id" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded btn-fw px-4 py-2 mx-1">View</a>
    <a asp-action="Update" asp-route-memberId="@item.Id" class="btn btn-warning btn-rounded btn-fw text-white px-4 py-2 mx-1">Update</a>
    <a asp-action="SafeDelete" asp-route-memberId="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-fw px-4 py-2 mx-1">Delete</a>
</td>

My controller:
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromRoute]int memberId)
{
    var member = await _memberRepository.GetNonDeletedMemberById(memberId);
    var updateMemberVM = _mapper.Map<UpdateMemberVM>(member);

    return View(updateMemberVM);
}

I know there is a question like this, but I want to know if they changed the behaviour as I remember using it in .NET 5.0 without needing specify my route in HttpGet.

Your Update(int memberId)  action method doesn't have a [HttpGet] with a route-template set, so it inherits the default route, which has {id}, not {memberId}.

@Dai so, either I should create another app.MapControllerRoute or add my route to HttpGet. Am I getting it right?

I recommend putting the route template directly on the action (using [Route( "/etc/" )] or [HttpGet( "/etc/" )] rather than trying to use .MapControllerRoute.

@Dai, okay, will do. Thanks for you answer. Was this behaviour changed after .net 5.0, do you have information about it? Because I am remembering using it without problem

I don't believe so; on the contrary, I don't think your code would have ever worked in any version of ASP.NET Core; but rather than trying to remember you should find out for sure: so I suggest you do a git checkout of your codebase when it targeted ASP.NET Core 5 and see if it worked back then.

The behavior you're describing hasn't changed in ASP.NET Core 5 or later versions. The generation of URLs with route parameters in ASP.NET Core still depends on how you configure your routes and how you generate links in your views.
